# Using RegEx on TextBox OnKeyPress not being able to press Tab button in the keyboard

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I am using RegEx in JavaScript for the restrictions that user cannot enter any key except what it is being allowed in the RegEx characters and I have assigned that JavaScript function containing the RegEx to the OnKeyPress on the TextBox. Unfortunately, when I press Tab in the keyboard, it does not allow me to move to the next control.

Here is the code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="Field:" onkeypress="return AlphaNumericTextBox(event)" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false"></asp:TextBox>

function AlphaNumericTextBox(event) {
            var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\b\t]+$");

            var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);

            if (!regex.test(key)) {
                event.preventDefault();

                return false;
            }
        }
```

Anyone could help me? I am sure that **"/t"** is a character code in RegEx for Tab key in the keyboard. I have tested it and only when I press Tab key in the keyboard, it does not allow me, it is only allow me to press: alphanumeric and the backspace.

Your answer much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you not using KeyCode?

Comment: There is no particular reason @JordanDavis. At first I also restrict it by KeyCode instead of RegEx, but it is due to the how the code looks like to me, it is looks like simpler when using RegEx rather than KeyCode

Comment: I'll show you practical use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) built-in javascript function. Doesn't get any more efficient than that right there :D

Syntax --- `arr.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex = 0])`

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/94kzcsn1/)

---

Related Links:

- [W3C Key and Character Codes vs. Event Types](http://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys-cancel2.html)

//CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<script>
function keyFilter(key){
    var filter = [97,98,99,100]; //a,b,c,d
    if(filter.indexOf(key) >= 0){ 
        console.log("a,b,c,d - filter");
    }
    else{
        console.log("everything else");
    }
}
</script>   
</head>
<body>  
    <textarea onkeypress="keyFilter(event.keyCode);"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @Jordan Davis.